# Using ST_Intersects ST_Overlaps ST_within and ST_Equals at the same time

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, geospatial

Currently using Grimzy Laravel MySQL Spatial, but this is basically just converting it to proper SQL queries.

I need to search whether an area intersects or overlaps or within or equal or contains to the polygon stored in DB.

```
public function __construct($areaPerimeterCoordinates = null)
{
    $this->area = Polygon::fromJson($areaPerimeterCoordinates);
}

public function handle()
{
    //this is the first query - it is working and returning result
    //need to refine it to check contains/same
    //$query = Property::intersects('area_perimeter', $this->area);  

    //working on this query - this returns empty
    $query = Property::where(function($qry) {
        $qry->intersects('area_perimeter', $this->area);
    })->orWhere(function($qry) {
        $qry->overlaps('area_perimeter', $this->area);
    })->orWhere(function($qry) {
        $qry->within('area_perimeter', $this->area);
    })->orWhere(function($qry) {
        $qry->equals('area_one_perimeter', $this->area);
    })->orWhere(function($qry) {
        $qry->contains('area_perimeter', $this->area);
    });

    $properties = $query->get();

    if(!$properties->isEmpty()) {
        throw new PropertyExistsException(null, $properties);
    }
}
```

Note: As per checking the first query and editing it to use groupings by adding a closure, it also returns empty. Weird?

```
$query = Property::where(function($qry) {
    $qry->intersects('area_perimeter', $this->area);
});

$properties = $query->get();//empty
```

Additional note: Now this ST_intersect sometimes work and sometimes does not work...

Really appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: If two areas are barely touching each other, roundoff error can get in the way of getting a solid answer.

Comment: Apparently, you can only use 1 spatial built-in function at a time (atleast from my test). Maybe I am wrong, but that is my findings as of now.